# Why my UITableView separators are missing when using custom cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm creating a custom cell and when I use it, my tableview separator just disappear. 
I was looking for an answer but I believe I already did something wrong, against the default behavior.

Here comes my screen

[image: loading]

While it's loads, I can see the separators between the cells.

Right after the content comes

[image]

The separators between the custom cells disappears but if I scroll down, it shows the separators to the empty cells.
I already tried to change the height of my custom cell, without success.

Comment: could be the inset color is lost with the white background. Have you tried changing the separator color? something like self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blackColor()

Comment: @Sneak you are right! I already flag it as duplicated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check your cells height ,maybe it bigger than the height you set on the delegate method or on the storyboard!
- Make them same you could see the separators

Answer (score 2):

It could be rendering issue on the simulator. Have you tried on running on device?

Also, try disabling following setting

iOS Simulator -> Debug > Optimize Rendering for Window Scale